# Plotting bar plot below xyplot with same x-axis?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to plot different types of plots (line plot and bar charts) beneath one another, they all have the same axis:

```
c1 <- ggplot(data, aes(date, TotalMutObs)) + stat_smooth(se = FALSE) + 
            geom_point() + 
            opts(axis.title.x = theme_blank()) +
            ylab("Cumulative number of new mutations")   
c2 <- ggplot(data, aes(date, distance)) + stat_smooth(se = FALSE) + 
            geom_point() + 
            opts(axis.title.x = theme_blank()) + 
            ylab("Cumulative mean pairwise distance")   
c3 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = NbOfHorses)) + 
            geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
            opts(axis.title.x = theme_blank()) + 
            ylab("Number of horses sampled")

grid.arrange(c1, c2,c3)
```

However, the dates on the x-axis are not lining up for the different plots.[image]

Here is some data to try it out:

```
date<-c("2003-03-13","2003-03-25","2003-03-26","2003-03-27","2003-03-28","2003-03-31","2003-04-01","2003-04-02","2003-04-04","2003-04-08","2003-04-09","2003-04-10","2003-04-11","2003-04-14","2003-04-15","2003-04-17","2003-04-19","2003-04-21","2003-04-22","2003-04-28","2003-05-08");

NbOfHorses<-c("1","2","1","3","4","5","4","3","3","3","3","4","2","4","1","2","4","1","2","1","2");

TotalMutObs<-c("20","30","58","72","140","165","204","230","250","286","302","327","346","388","393","414","443","444","462","467","485");

distance<-c("0.000693202","0.00073544","0.000855432","0.000506876","0.000720193","0.000708047","0.000835468","0.000812401","0.000803149","0.000839117","0.000842048","0.000856393","0.000879973","0.000962382","0.000990666","0.001104861","0.001137515","0.001143838","0.00121874","0.001213737","0.001201379");

data<-as.data.frame(cbind(date,NbOfHorses,TotalMutObs,distance));
```

Cheers,
Joseph

Comment: Isn't there an `xlim()` function in ggplot2? Something like `c3 <- c3+xlim(range(data$dates))`

Comment: I don't think that is the problem because all three x-axis span exactly the same range.

Comment: Put some data forward and we'll test it.

Comment: You are correct. The problem lies in the width of the y-axis labels. The ranges are actually all the same. The data offered throws errors with that code because cbind creates a matrix. Better to replace that code with the output of dput(data).

Comment: Should have put as.data.frame. It should work now. There must be a way to fix the origin of the x-axis to align all the plots. Any ideas?

Comment: Arrrgggh! Don't use as.data.frame(cbind(.)) Now everything is a factor. It completely messes up your plots. Please use dput().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to solve this problem is to work within **ggplot2** and get creative about stacking copies of your data and then sending subsets to each geom that you need.

```
#A version of your data cleaned up
dat <- data.frame(date = as.Date(date),NbOfHorses = as.numeric(NbOfHorses),
                TotalMutObs = as.numeric(TotalMutObs),distance = as.numeric(distance))

#Create three copies, one for each panel
# Use informative titles for grp to be panel titles    
fullDat <- rbind(dat,dat,dat)
fullDat$grp <- rep(c('Cumulative number of new mutations',
                        'Cumulative mean pairwise distance',
                        'Number of horses sampled'),each = nrow(dat))

ggplot(fullDat,aes(x = date)) + 
    facet_wrap(~grp,nrow = 3,scale = "free_y") + 
    geom_point(data = subset(fullDat,grp == 'Cumulative number of new mutations'),
        aes(y = TotalMutObs)) + 
    stat_smooth(data = subset(fullDat,grp == 'Cumulative number of new mutations'),
        aes(y = TotalMutObs),se = FALSE) + 
    geom_point(data = subset(fullDat,grp == 'Cumulative mean pairwise distance'),
        aes(y = distance)) + 
    stat_smooth(data = subset(fullDat,grp == 'Cumulative mean pairwise distance'),
        aes(y = distance),se = FALSE) + 
    geom_bar(data = subset(fullDat,grp == 'Number of horses sampled'),
        aes(y = NbOfHorses),stat = "identity") + 
    labs(x = NULL,y = NULL)
```

[image]