# R-Lattice package: 1 x-axis for multiple y-axes

Tags: r, lattice

My question is similar to this:
[Plotting bar plot below xyplot with same x-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028137/plotting-bar-plot-below-xyplot-with-same-x-axis), but for the lattice package rather than ggplot.

I have 21 xyplots, all with the same x-axis scale, but different y-axis scales. I would like to plot all 21 lines with only 1 x-axis, but 21 different y-axes scales (one row per line). I nearly have it here:[image: 21 xyplots, 1 x-axis], but the redundant x-axes printed to each panel make this figure ridiculous. My script:

```
xyplot(numhr~year | spp, xlab = "Time(years)", 
ylab = "Abundance (# per party hr)", type = "l", aspect = "fill",
strip = FALSE, scales = list(relation = "free"), as.table = TRUE,
layout = c(1,21), xlim = c(1940,2010))
```

Any help?

~Kevin

Comment: possibly `scales=list(y=list(relation="free"))` ... ?

Comment: Yup! That does it exactly, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment above, the necessary change to my code to make this work involves adding 'y = list(relation = "free")' to the 'scales' component. Edited code below:

```
xyplot(numhr~year | spp, xlab = "Time(years)", 
ylab = "Abundance (# per party hr)", type = "l", aspect = "fill",
strip = FALSE, scales = list(y = list(relation = "free")), as.table = TRUE,
layout = c(1,21), xlim = c(1940,2010))
```

Which produces this (unfortunately the y-axes are still too condensed, but this does address the question originally posed):
[image: Improved xyplot with 1 x-axis]